# Ruby on Rails: Unable to retrieve regex from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have set of regexes which I stored in some table in DB. I retrieve them and apply some operation using those regexes but they are not working as desired.

```
junkremoveregex=[]
    regexes = JunkRemoveLineRegex.find(:all,:select => 'regex')

    regexes.each do |regex|
      junkremoveregex << regex.regex
    end

    puts junkremoveregex

    junktest=/note/

    junkremoveregexset=Regexp.union(junkremoveregex)
    line ="note thhat yo yo honey singh".downcase
    if(line.match(junkremoveregexset))
      puts "note was found in line"
    else
      puts "No line was found"
    end
```

The output of this code is No line was found.

If I use this code then its working perfectly

```
junkremoveregex=[]
    regexes = JunkRemoveLineRegex.find(:all,:select => 'regex')

    regexes.each do |regex|
      junkremoveregex << regex.regex
    end

    puts junkremoveregex

    junktest=/note/

    junkremoveregexset=Regexp.union(junktest)
    line ="note thhat yo yo honey singh".downcase
    if(line.match(junkremoveregexset))
      puts "note was found in line"
    else
      puts "No line was found"
    end
```

Puts junkremoveregex gives /note/

How can this problem be solved ?

Comment: Please show the contents of `JunkRemoveLineRegex.find(:all,:select => 'regex')`

Comment: As we need to see what you actually have for the regex's you've stored.

Comment: Puts junkremoveregex gives /note/ . I think I have specified this in question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **BroiSatse** mentioned, your regex is coming in string format, you need to first convert it back to regex format. For that you need to use this gem http://rubygems.org/gems/to_regexp

```
"/note/".to_regexp
#=> /note/
```

or in your case

```
junkremoveregexset.to_regexp
```

Comment: it worked !! just checking above solution as it doesn't require any dependency

Answer (score 0):

If they are stored as strings you may need to do:

```
>> Regexp.new junkremoveregex
```

Comment: junkremoveregex is an array, `Regexp.new` does not accept it as an argument`.

Answer (score 0):

If `puts junkremoveregex` prints `/note/` it means that this is a string `"/note/". Do not treat those slashes as regex syntax - it is rather part of the regex itself, so your regex becomes:

```
/\/note\//
```

This obviously doesn't match anything. **You need to modify your model not to include those slashes.**

Apart from that `Regexp.union` does not convert strings into Regex so, you need to do it before you union your conditions. I would write your code like this:

```
junkremoveregex = JunkRemoveLineRegex.pluck(:regex).map {|string| Regexp.new string }

puts junkremoveregex

junktest=/note/

junkremoveregexset=Regexp.union(junkremoveregex)
line ="note thhat yo yo honey singh".downcase
if(line.match(junkremoveregexset))
  puts "note was found in line"
else
  puts "No line was found"
end
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `pluck' for #<Class:0x00000008b192b8>. This error is thrown !! Actually I am new to rails development

Comment: @LearningBasics - Which rails version do you use?

Comment: rails version is 3.1.0

Comment: Forget about `pluck` then, it has been added in Rails 3.2 :(